# Java Couchbase Querying to find a document's ID?

Tags: java, couchbase

I'm new to couchbase. I'm using Java for this. I'm trying to remove a document from a bucket by looking up its ID with query parameters(assuming the ID is unknown).

Lets say I have a bucket called test-data. In that bucked I have a document with ID of 555 and Content of `{"name":"bob","num":"10"}`
I want to be able to remove that document by querying using 'name' and 'num'.

So far I have this (hardcoded):

```
String statement = "SELECT META(`test-data`).id from `test-data` WHERE name = \"bob\" and num = \"10\"";
N1qlQuery query = N1qlQuery.simple(statement);   
N1qlQueryResult result = bucket.query(query);
List<N1qlQueryRow> row = result.allRows();
N1qlQueryRow res1 = row.get(0);
System.out.println(res1); 
//output: {"id":"555"}
```

So I'm getting a json that has the document's ID in it. What would be the best way to extract that ID so that I can then remove the queryed document from the bucket using its ID? Am I doing to many steps? Is there a better way to extract the document's ID?

```
bucket.remove(docID)
```

Ideally I'd like to use something like a N1q1QueryResult to get this going but I'm not sure how to set that up.

```
N1qlQueryResult result = bucket.query(select("META.id").fromCurrentBucket().where((x("num").eq("\""+num+"\"")).and(x("name").eq("\""+name+"\""))));
```

But that isn't working at the moment.

Any help or direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Update: Figured out  ' String docID = res1.value().getString("id"); ' will get the document ID in a usable string, but still wondering if there is a better or more concise way of doing this.

Comment: Also figured out the N1q1Query should be: bucket.query(select("META(`test-data`).id").fromCurrentBucket()

So now I have it down to 4 lines.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way which is running this kind of query:

```
delete from `test-data` use keys '00000874a09e749ab6f199c0622c5cb0' returning raw META(`test-data`).id
```

or if your fields has index:

```
delete from `test-data` where name='bob' and num='10' returning raw META(`test-data`).id
```

This query deletes the specified document with given document key (which is meta.id) and returns document id of deleted document if it deletes any document. Returns empty if no documents deleted.

You can implement this query with couchbase sdk as follows:

```
Statement statement = deleteFrom("test-data")
    .where(x("name").eq(s("bob")).and(x("num").eq(s("10"))))
    .returningRaw(meta(i("test-data")).get("id"));
```

You can make this statement parameterized or just execute like that.